# New Teams doesn't show Banner (Desktop) Notifications for Activity Notifications

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

In 'new' Teams, Activity Notifications are received successfully in the Activity Feed, but Banner (Desktop) notifications are not shown.

I am using [sendActivityNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-sendactivitynotification?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#example-2-notify-a-user-about-an-event-using-a-custom-topic) Graph API with `custom` topic to send important updates to users.

The app is installed as a `static tab` in `personal` scope.

Since the notifications themselves work, I assume that Graph permissions, `manifest.json` and the API request body are configured correctly.

Toggling back to 'old/classic' Teams resolves the issue (Banners start showing up again).

I get the same result in both - Desktop and Web - variants of 'new' Teams.

###### Some additional details:

New Teams Version (Desktop):

> You have Microsoft Teams version 23320.3021.2567.4799(preview).
> You've got the latest version. It was last updated on 5/1/2024.
> The client version is 49/23113028718.

New Teams Version (Web):

> The client version is 1415/23111630013.

Teams Notification Settings for my App:

> Show in Activity and Banner

Library:

> JavaScript (NodeJS) - `createMicrosoftGraphClientWithCredential` from `@microsoft/teamsfx`

Comment: Hello @sjoshi_sct - 
I tried to call the HTTP request using Graph Explorer, but it is throwing the error due to installation id as user should install the app. I will setup this sample and try to check it once: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/graph-activity-feed/nodejs/server.js

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft do you have any update on this one? Do you need me to share any additional details?

Comment: Similar issue is being tracked here at https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/new-teams-desktop-banner-notifications-don-t-work-with/m-p/4003041#M9064.